# How does make your code that has GUI run on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyqt5, instance

I have a python code based on PyQt5 and Pymongo library suppose when it runs , it shows  GUI window with some pushing buttons; however, I want to make it run on Amazon  Ubuntu instance ; however, I brought Ubuntu instance from amazon installed Anaconda alongside VNSserver and Ubuntu Desktop GUI to be able to run my code using spyder application and view the my application's GUI it shows an error everytime I run my code as below

```
No module named pymongo
I verified that pymongo is installed and work by writing some code using the terminal it works perfect.
```

At the same time , when I run my code from the console using python main.py  it shows another error which is

```
Could not connect to any X display
```

Screenshot from the terminal shows the python and pymongo version installed.
[image]

How does my code out when I run it on my local machine.
[image]

Comment: can you show how did you get the error "No module named pymongo" ?

Comment: Yeah , I am just pressing run button in spyder which installed on the instance  then it shows this error .

Comment: I think the main issue here is the X-server not the python lib. try to fix X-Server first by running command like $xclock and make sure it displays clock to your personal computer.